# Printing values of an Array that are in odd numbers of columns and rows

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf

I have to create a program that prints an array with user specified number of rows and columns, and print values that are have an odd index(both the row# and column#)

This is what I managed to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r, c, i, j;
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    int A[r][c];
    printf("Enter your numbers\n");

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        printf("\n\t");
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

If the user specifies that he wants 4 rows and 4 columns the program will print something like this:

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X 
X X X X
```

How would one make so the program would print:

```
X   X  // prints only for odd columns (1st and 3rd)
       //  prints nothing as the index of row is even(2nd)
X   X // same as 1st row
      // smae as 2nd row
```

Comment: Replace the `i++` and `j++` in the printing loops with `i += 2` and `j += 2`.

Comment: ...and the odd index would need loops like `for (i = 1; i < r; i+=2)` similar for `j`. Unless the human world is counting from 1 and not 0.

Comment: Decide display width `#define WIDTH 1`,  `if((i & 1) || (j & 1))
     printf("%*s ", WIDTH, "");
    else
        printf("%*d ", WIDTH, A[i][j]);`

Answer (score 1):

From your example it looks like you're considering the first row and column (index `0s`) to the the first odd ones...as in row and column `1` perhaps.

In that case, in your print function you could simple change the incrementing fields to...

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    printf("\n\t");

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j += 2)
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

...or you could use the `modulus (%)` operator to check the status of the values of `j` being even or odd...

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    printf("\n\t");

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) //will print columns at index 0, 2, 4, 6, ...
                printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer the first though...

---

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the blank spaces in your output where the rows were not odd numbers, do not change the incrementation of `i`, that way it will print `\n` every time to maintain those blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you want to print 1..3...5...7 index instead of incrementing one each time in your for loop, also, start your index at 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int r, c, i, j;
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    int A[r][c];
    printf("Enter your numbers\n");

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < r; i+=2) {
        printf("\n\t");
        for (j = 1; j < c; j+=2)
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are just learning C, then one of the most valuable lessons you can learn is to *ALWAYS VALIDATE USER INPUT*. It doesn't take much to do, just check the **return** of `scanf` and, if a successful conversion takes place, then validate the value received is within your allowable range. For instance, since your `rows` and `column` input are for array bounds, they must be greater than `0`, so you could do:

```
int rtn = 0;
printf ("Number of rows: ");
/* VALIDATE all user input */
if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &r)) != 1 || r < 1) {
    if (rtn == EOF) {   /* respect cancellation of input with EOF */
        putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of rows provided.\n");
    /* handle error as desired */
}
```

Now if you want to present your prompt again, if an invalid `row` value is entered, you can simply put the whole routine in an infinite loop and `break` when valid input is entered, e.g.

```
for (;;) {
    int rtn = 0;
    printf ("Number of rows: ");
    /* VALIDATE all user input */
    if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &r)) != 1 || r < 1) {
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* respect cancellation of input with EOF */
            putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */
            return 1;
        }
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of rows provided.\n");
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Next, there is no need to use expensive `modulo` (`'%'`) testing, all you really care about to print the *odd* `row` and `col` values is that your `col` value is NOT an *odd* value (since array indexes are *zero-based* in C, the first, third, fifth, etc.. columns will all have an *even* value), so just check the *LEAST SIGNIFICANT BIT* for the column, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        if (!(j & 0x1))  /* check if the first bit of the column is 0 */
            printf ("%2d  ", A[i][j]);   /* print the number */
        else
            printf ("__  ");            /* print an equivalent blank */
    putchar ('\n');     /* never use printf for a single char */
}
```

If you wanted shorter, albeit a bit less readable code, you could use the `ternary` operator to control the test and printing, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        !(j & 0x1) ? printf ("%2d  ", A[i][j]) : printf ("__  ");
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

To accommodate printing only odd `rows`, just check if the *lest significant bit* of the `row` is odd and skip the row entirely, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    if (i & 0x1) {      /* skip printing of even rows */
        putchar ('\n');
        continue;
    }            
    ...
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)     /* make clear no arguments are expected */
{
    int r, c, i, j;

    for (;;) {
        int rtn = 0;
        printf ("Number of rows: ");
        /* VALIDATE all user input */
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &r)) != 1 || r < 1) {
            if (rtn == EOF) {   /* respect cancellation of input with EOF */
                putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */
                return 1;
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of rows provided.\n");
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    for (;;) {
        int rtn = 0;
        printf ("Number of columns: ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1 || c < 1) {
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                putchar ('\n');
                return 1;
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of columns provided.\n");
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    int A[r][c];

    printf ("Enter your numbers\n");

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            if (scanf ("%d", &A[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid array input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        if (i & 0x1) {      /* skip printing of even rows */
            putchar ('\n');
            continue;
        }            
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            if (!(j & 0x1))  /* check if the first bit of the column is 0 */
                printf ("%2d  ", A[i][j]);   /* print the number */
            else
                printf ("__  ");            /* print an equivalent blank */
        putchar ('\n');     /* never use printf for a single char */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_prnodd
Number of rows: 4
Number of columns: 4
Enter your numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 1  __   3  __

 9  __  11  __
```